# pysipp - Trying to use it with existing sipp conf file

Tags: python, sipp, pysipp

**Background**

I have an existing sipp conf file that I launch like so:

```
sipp mysipdomain.net -sf ./testcall.conf -m 1 -s 12345 -i 10.1.1.1:5060
```

This runs just fine. It simulates a call in our test labs.  But now I need to expand this test to make it a part of a larger test script where not only do I launch the sipp test, but I prove (via sip trace) that it's hitting the right boxes.

I decided to wrap this sipp call in python.  I just found https://github.com/SIPp/pysipp and am trying to see if I can write this entire test in python.  To start, i tried to run the same sipp test using pysipp.

**Problem / Question**

I'm currently getting an error that says:

```
lab2:/tmp/jj/sipp_tests# python mvv_numeric.py
No handlers could be found for logger "pysipp"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mvv_numeric.py", line 6, in <module>
    uac()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysipp-0.1.alpha-py2.7.egg/pysipp/agent.py", line 71, in __call__
    raise_exc=raise_exc, **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pluggy.py", line 724, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pluggy.py", line 338, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pluggy.py", line 333, in <lambda>
    _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pluggy.py", line 596, in execute
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysipp-0.1.alpha-py2.7.egg/pysipp/__init__.py", line 250, in pysipp_run_protocol
    finalize(cmds2procs, raise_exc=raise_exc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysipp-0.1.alpha-py2.7.egg/pysipp/__init__.py", line 228, in finalize
    raise SIPpFailure(msg)
pysipp.SIPpFailure: Some agents failed
'uac' with exit code 255 -> Command or syntax error: check stderr output
```

**Code**

Here's what the py script looks like:

```
  1 import pysipp
  2 uac = pysipp.client(destaddr=('mysipdomain.net', 5060))
  3 uac.uri_username = '12345'
  4 uac.auth_password = ''
  5 uac.scen_file = './numeric.xml'
  6 uac()
```

And the original sipp "testcall.conf" has been renamed to "numeric.xml" and looks like this: (I'm only including the first part because it's quite long.  if you need to see something specific, please let me know and I will add to this post)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE scenario SYSTEM "sipp.dtd">
<scenario name="UAC with Media">
<send retrans="10000">
<![CDATA[

      INVITE sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port] SIP/2.0
      Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port];branch=[branch]
      From: sipp <sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]>;tag=[pid]SIPpTag00[call_number]
      To: [service] <sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port]>
      Call-id: [call_id]
      CSeq: 1 INVITE
      Contact: <sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]>
      Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, INFO, MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PRACK, UPDATE, REFER
      User-Agent: PolycomVVX-VVX_300-UA/5.5.2.8571
      Accept-Language: en
      Supported: replaces,100rel
      Allow-Events: conference,talk,hold
      Max-Forwards: 70
      Content-Type: application/sdp
      Content-Length: [len]
```

I'm sure it's something simple I've overlooked.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

***EDIT:***

I added debug level logging and reran the python script.  In the logs I can now see what pysipp is actually attempting:

```
2018-01-31 14:40:32,715 MainThread [DEBUG] pysipp launch.py:63 : launching cmd:
"'/usr/bin/sipp' 'mysipdomain.net':'5060' -s '12345' -sn 'uac' -sf 'numeric.xml' -recv_timeout '5000' -r '1' -l '1' -m '1' -log_file '/tmp/uac_log_file' -screen_file '/tmp/uac_screen_file' -trace_logs -trace_screen "
```

So comparing that with the original command line I use to run sipp, I see the extra "-sn 'uac'".

Going to see about either getting my SIPP script to work with that tag or ... google to see if I can find other similar posts.
In the meantime, if you see my mistake, i'm all ears.

Comment: next time an issue on the Github project would be useful as I'm not sure the SIPp team hangs on SO that much unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here (as you noticed) is likely that `pysipp.client()` sets the `-sn uac` flag and `sipp` fails having both `-sn` and `-sf`.

To see the actual error you can enable logging before running the `client`:

```
import pysipp

pysipp.utils.log_to_stderr("DEBUG")

uac = pysipp.client(destaddr=('mysipdomain.net', 5060))
uac.uri_username = '12345'
uac.auth_password = ''
uac.scen_file = './numeric.xml'
uac()
```

The hack is to simply do `uac.scen_name = None` but the proper way to do this is to either use `pysipp.scenario()` ([docs here](https://github.com/SIPp/pysipp#multiple-agents)) and rename your `numeric.xml` to have `uac` in the file name (i.e. `uac_numeric.xml`) or use instead `pysipp.ua(scen_file=<path/to/numeric.xml>)`.

To understand the problem the `client` is [currently applying a default *scenario name* argument](https://github.com/SIPp/pysipp/blob/master/pysipp/agent.py#L191) when really the user should be able to override that (though in that case there'll be no guarantee that the user actually is sending *client traffic* which renders the name *client* kind of pointless).